# Dropdownlist multicolum dentro de grilla(Angular)

Tags: css

tengo un problema con mi dropdowlist dentro de una grilla, como puedo hacer para que el dropdownlist se muestre completo, y no truncado por el contenedor

[image: screenshot]

Al mover las barras de desplazamiento, sí se muestra completo, pero al soltar la barra, el dropwlist se oculta

[image: selecciono barra vertical]

Cual sería la solución?

Este es el código HTML(angular)

```
<div class="my-3 px-3">         
    <div class="siaf-card shadow border-0 py-1 mb-2 h-100">
        <div class="table-responsive h-100">
            <div class="table-sticky h-100">
                <table class="table m-0" aria-describedby="">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th id="metaorigen">Meta(Origen)</th>
                            <th id="fn">Fn</th>
                            <th id="divf">DivF</th>
                            <th id="grpf">GrpF</th>
                            <th id="prod">Prod/Pry</th>
                            <th id="act">Act/AI/Obr</th>
                            <th id="finalidad">Finalidad</th>
                            <th id="prg">Prg</th>
                            <th id="codmeta">Meta</th>
                            <th id="descripcion">Descripción de Meta</th>
                            <th id="unidad">Unidad</th>
                            <th id="metadestino">Meta(Destino)</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="c-pointer-none" *ngIf="(!listaDeequivalenciametas || listaDeequivalenciametas.length === 0 || isLoading) , else listaequivalenciametas">
                            <td colspan="100%">
                                <siaf-loading *ngIf="isLoading"></siaf-loading>
                                <span *ngIf="!isLoading" class="m-0 d-block text-center">:: Sin registro ::</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <ng-template #listaequivalenciametas>
                            <tr *ngFor="let item of listaDeequivalenciametas; let i = index" >
                                <td class="text-uppercase">{{ item.sec_fun }}</td>
                                <td class="text-uppercase">{{ item.funcion }}</td>
                                <td class="text-uppercase">{{ item.division_funcional }}</td>
                                <td class="text-uppercase">{{ item.grupo_funcional }}</td>
                                <td class="text-uppercase">{{ item.prod_proy }}</td>
                                <td class="text-uppercase">{{ item.act_ai_obr }}</td>
                                <td class="text-uppercase">{{ item.finalidad }}</td>
                                <td class="text-uppercase">{{ item.programa_institucional }}</td>
                                <td class="text-uppercase">{{ item.meta }}</td>
                                <td class="text-uppercase">{{ item.nombre }}</td>
                                <td class="text-uppercase">{{ item.nombre_unidad }}</td>
                                <td class="text-uppercase">
                                    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
                                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Todos</button>                    
                                        <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1" style="width: 600px;">
                                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                                <div>
                                                 Meta
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                 Fn
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                 DivF
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                 GrpF
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                 Prg
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                 Prod/Pry
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                 Act/AI/Obr
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                 Finalidad
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                 Cod
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                 Descriçion
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div ngbDropdownItem class="d-flex justify-content-between" *ngFor="let item of listaDeequivalenciametas; let i = index" [ngClass]="{ 'active': equivalenciameta.secEjec == item.secEjec && equivalenciameta.anno == item.anno && equivalenciameta.fase == item.fase && equivalenciameta.sec_fun == item.sec_fun}" (click)="elegirmetadestino(item)">
                                                <div>
                                                    {{ item.sec_fun }}
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    {{ item.funcion }}
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    {{ item.division_funcional }}
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    {{ item.grupo_funcional }}
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    {{ item.programa_institucional }}
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    {{ item.prod_proy }}
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    {{ item.act_ai_obr }}
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    {{ item.finalidad }}
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    {{ item.meta }}
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    {{ item.nombre }}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>                                             
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                           
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ng-template>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Estoy usando ngbDropdown para crear un dropdowlist dentro de una celda td